# ¿Cómo definir el tamaño de un array por teclado en C?

Tags: array, c

Necesito crear un array y que el tamaño de este sea definido por el usuario en un `scanf`. Estoy probando de todo pero nada. Si lo hago de esta manera me salta un error diciendo que la expresión dentro de los [] debe tener un valor constante.

```
printf("Introduce la cantidad de números que deseas ordenar:\n");
            scanf("%d", &cantidad);
            double [cantidad] = {};
```

Comment: hay un error en el código y aparece que el array no está declarado pero lo está. seria double orden[cantidad] = {}

Comment: Que compilador estás usando??

Answer (score 1):

Esto en C no existe:

```c
double [cantidad] = {};
```

En cambio si hacemos esto:

```c
double orden[cantidad] = {};
```

También estará mal, porque los [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (Variable-length array) no pueden ser inicializados. Sin embargo, no todos los compiladores admiten VLA, así que por cuestión de portabilidad, no lo deberías usar.

Si quieres pedir el tamaño por teclado, debes usar memoria dinámica (con [malloc](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)):

```c
printf("Introduce la cantidad de números que deseas ordenar:\n");
scanf("%d", &cantidad);
double* orden = malloc(cantidad * sizeof(double));
```

Por supuesto, debes incluir la cabecera `stdlib.h` para poder usar la función `malloc`.

También puedes usar los indizadores (aunque `orden` sea un puntero):

```c
orden[0] = 100;
```

**Nota:** Cuando trabajas con memoria dinámica, debes liberar la memoria manualmente con [free](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/).

Answer (score 0):

Segun el código que estas mostrando, no estas declarando bien el arreglo, fijate el proceso es: declarar nombre de variable, luego tipo, apartar el tamallo de memoria con malloc

(nombre de la variable) = (tipo) (apartar memorio)  (tamaño)

miArreglo=(double)*malloc(cantidad*sizeof(double));

por lo que cambiaria el código a algo como esto:

```
printf("Introduce la cantidad de números que deseas ordenar:\n");
scanf("%d", &cantidad);
miArreglo=(double)*malloc(cantidad*sizeof(double));
```

Answer (score 0):

C soporta arreglos de largo variable desde C99, por lo que es legitimo definir un arreglo cuyo tamaño se conocerá en tiempo de ejecución. Expresiones como

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
double cuentas[n + 1];
```

son válidas.

El único requisito adicional es que la(s) variable(s) usadas en la inicialización **no** debe estar inicializadas. Si lo estuvieran, entonces el compilador calcularía el tamaña en tiempo de compilación, que no es lo que se desea.

Los cambios al código fueron los requeridos para hacerlo válido:

- Eliminar la inicialización.
- Darle un nombre al arreglo.

Código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int cantidad;
    printf("Introduce la cantidad de números que deseas ordenar:\n");
    scanf("%d", &cantidad);
    double orden[cantidad];
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
        orden[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", (int) orden[i]);
    }
}
```

produce:

```
Introduce la cantidad de números que deseas ordenar:
10
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Ese código no le compilará al OP, puesto él dijo lo siguiente: *Si lo hago de esta manera me salta un error diciendo que la expresión dentro de los [] debe tener un valor constante..* A partir de C11 los VLA son opcionales, así que no se asegura que un compilador admita VLA.

Comment: @MrDave1999. Correcto. El ánimo de mi respuesta es mostrar que su lógica es válida según algunos compiladores en uso. Esto no debe interpretarse como un respaldo a las técnicas descritas.